# Adding model into another view model's collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

## The Setup

So I'm working on a project in which there exists a `MainViewModel` class. This `MainViewModel` contains a list of `Soldiers` through an observable collection. I have a button in the `MainView` which displays a new `AddSoldierView`. The `AddSoldierView` is binding to elements from the `AddSoldierViewModel`. The `AddSoldierView` is basically a form where the user inputs all of the data for that soldier.

## The Problem

Now that I have the `Soldier`'s information on the `AddSoldierViewModel`, I want to be able to add that back into the ObservableCollection of the `MainViewModel`. I have binded a command to the button (Add Soldier) on the `AddSoldierView`, but I'm not sure how to get that information back into the `MainViewModel`.

## What I've tried

I've already setting up an event handler on the `AddSoldierViewModel` in which the `SoldierModel` is passed as an EventArg. But I can't get the event itself to trigger.

Any suggestions? I've been trying to stay true to the MVVM spirit, but there are still some kinks I'm trying to sort out. Let me know if you want to see some code snippets, UML diagrams, or whatever.

#### AddSoldierViewModel.cs

```
public class AddSoldierViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public event EventHandler<AddSoldierEventArgs> AddSoldierClicked;

    public ICommand AddSoldierCommand;

    private Soldier _soldier;

    public Soldier Soldier
    {
        get => _soldier;
        set
        {
            _soldier = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Soldier));
        }
    }

    public AddSoldierViewModel() 
    {
        AddSoldierCommand = new RelayCommand(AddSoldier);
    }

    private void AddSoldier()
    {
        OnAddSoldierClicked(new AddSoldierEventArgs()
        {
           Soldier = Soldier
        });
    }

    protected virtual void OnAddSoldierClicked(AddSoldierEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = AddSoldierClicked;
        handler?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

#### MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region - Private Properties -
    private Team _selectedTeam;
    private Soldier _selectedSoldier;
    #endregion // - Private Properties -

    #region // - Public Properties -
    public ObservableCollection<Soldier> Soldiers { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams { get; }
    public Team SelectedTeam
    {
        get => _selectedTeam;
        set
        {
            _selectedTeam = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedTeam));
        }
    }
    public Soldier SelectedSoldier
    {
        get => _selectedSoldier;
        set
        {
            _selectedSoldier = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedSoldier));
        }
    }
    #endregion // - Public Properties -

    #region // - Commands -
    public ICommand DeleteTeamCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand AddSoldierDialogCommand { get; private set; }
    #endregion // - Commands -

    #region  - Services -
    public IDialogService AddSoldierDialogService { get; private set; }
    #endregion // - Services -

    #region - Constructors -
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Soldiers = new ObservableCollection<Soldier>();
        Teams = new ObservableCollection<Team>();

        Soldiers.CollectionChanged += Soldiers_CollectionChanged;
        Teams.CollectionChanged += Teams_CollectionChanged;

        DeleteTeamCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteTeam);
        AddSoldierDialogCommand = new RelayCommand(AddSoldierDialog);

        AddSoldierDialogService = new AddSoldierDialogService();
    }

    #endregion // - Constructors -

    #region - Methods -
    private void AddSoldierDialog()
    {
        AddSoldierViewModel addSoldierViewModel = new AddSoldierViewModel();
        addSoldierViewModel.AddSoldierClicked += AddSoldierViewModel_AddSoldierClicked;
        AddSoldierDialogService.ShowDialog(addSoldierViewModel);
    }

    private void AddSoldierViewModel_AddSoldierClicked(object sender, AddSoldierEventArgs e)
    {
        Soldiers.Add(new Soldier(e.Soldier));
    }

    private void Teams_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
        {
        }
        foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
        {
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Teams));
    }

    private void Soldiers_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
        {
        }
        foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
        {
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Soldiers));
    }
    #endregion // - Methods -
}
```

Comment: An alternative to using the event (which is not incorrect at all) would be to inject a ICommand into the AddSoldierVM; this command could represent the "insert solder instance to list". Then, when you instantiate an AddSoldierVM from MainVM, you pass the command instance via constructor. In AddSolderVM, after populating the info you call the command injected.

Comment: @EmersonCardoso You're right! On this implementation (which I just added right now), I added an ICommand on the `AddSoldierViewModel` which is binded to the button on the dialog. This command fires the event which is caught by the `MainViewModel`, who then adds the `Soldier` to the ObservableCollection.

Comment: Further improvements could be model validation on the `AddSoldierViewModel` side which controls the `CanExecute()` of the RelayCommand.

Comment: Please avoid the use of "EDIT:" in your questions.  We [already know](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/364638/revisions) the question was edited.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `AddSoldierViewModel` is for a dialog box, I think you can make things a lot simpler.  The only thing that needs to change is the `AddSoldierDialog()` method:

```
private void AddSoldierDialog()
{
    AddSoldierViewModel addSoldierViewModel = new AddSoldierViewModel();

    if(AddSoldierDialogService.ShowDialog(addSoldierViewModel) == true)
    {
        Soldiers.Add(addSoldierViewModel.Soldier);
    }
}
```

The return value of `ShowDialog()` should be `bool?`, where `true` means the user closed the dialog in a good state.  `false` would be closing the dialog in a bad state and `null` would be closing the dialog from the window itself.  Once you know the user intended to add that soldier, you can add it to your list directly.

This avoids complicated event routes and simplifies debugging.

---

Of course, *if* the use case of the "Add Soldier Dialog" were to *stay open* and allow the user to add multiple new soldiers before closing, then your event would be necessary.  Just make sure to unregister it when you don't need it any more.

Last comment would be if you do choose to keep the event, you handle copying the Soldier instance before you send it.  That way you don't have lingering bugs because somewhere someone thought the soldier in the event was unique.

In that case your click handler would look something like this:

```
private void RaiseAddSoldierClicked()
{
    AddSoldierClicked?.Invoke(this, new AddSoldierEventArgs
    {
        Soldier = new Soldier(Soldier)
    });
}
```

Handling that on the event source instead of all the listeners will help reduce unexpected bugs.

Answer (score 0):

So I've done some more messing around last night and I think I may have found a good solution for MVVM. I revisited the idea of the Event and added an EventHandler `AddSoldierClick` to the `AddSoldierVM`. I also created a custom EventArgs class to hold the selected `Soldier`.

When I instantiate a `AddSoldierVM` on my `MainVM`, I subscribe to the `AddSoldierClick` event and add the EventArg's `Soldier` object to my ObservableCollection in the `MainVM`.

After that, I just `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Soldiers))` in the `Soldiers_CollectionChanged()` event.

---

I'll go and post code snippets when I get home. But I decided to share this answer with you guys. Are there any other ways to go about it? I think this one is pretty clean (just gotta watch out for the potential memory leaks in subscribing to the event and forgetting to unsubscribe when the `MainVM` is done).

Comment: This is probably more appropriate as a comment.  We welcome the snippets and your explanation as an actual answer, when you have time, of course.